# Watson Conversation condition for checking if system entity @sys-date is today/yesterday

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-conversation, watson

I'm trying to create a dialog with different response/action depending on a @sys-date system entity provided by the user. I know I can add conditions such as *@sys-date.before('2018-01-24')* where the compared value is fixed, but I have not been able to create a conditions that would check if the provided system entity is during today or during yesterday. Best I've tried is *@sys-date.before(now().reformatDateTime('dd-MM-yyyy'))* but even that does not seem to work like expected.

Comment: hi and welcome to SO. Please post the code you have tried so far for a better question quality. https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: Found out a viable way for this, but it needs the caller to supply the dates of today and yesterday as context variables in format yyyy-MM-dd (e.g. 2018-02-01). With these variables in place, you can create a condition such as: `@sys-date.sameOrAfter(context['yesterday_string']) && @sys-date.before(context['today_string'])`

Answer (score 3):

You can find out date for today and yesterday as follows:

`{
  "context": {
   "date_today": "<? new Date().format('yyyy-MM-dd') ?>",
   "date_yesterday": "<? new Date((new Date().getTime()) - (24*60*60*1000L)).format('yyyy-MM-dd') ?>"
}`

These variables can be used then to compare the date in the system entity. E.g.

`@sys-date.before($date_yesterday)`